# Update submit function button on ServiceNow submit risk assessment

Tags: servicenow

I want to modify the function when submitting the risk assessment form.

[Risk assessment modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxBeu.png)

My goal is I want to add the user name who's taken the risk assessment before window reload (after I submit the risk assessment form it reloads the page)

[add user name before submit risk asssessment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngf6u.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create new field on risk assesment form and write below client script to populate the field by whoever filling the form out. I assume you create a reference field which is refering to "sys_user" table and the field name is : "Submitted by"

```
var usr = g_user.userID;

g_form.setValue('submitted_by',usr.getDisplayValue());
```